# Histogram in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, c++11, histogram

I'm programming an histogram for an determinate bidimensional array (which is filled with numbers that represent a numeric value of a color in a pixel -> matrizGrey) in C++. You have to introduce by parameter (argv[4]) the number of sections that the histogram will have, and the range is between 0 and 255.
So, depending on the number of sections, the histogram will change. I catched how it works (comparing the matrix element between the first element of the range and the next one) but my problem is that I can't do it recursive.
The following code show my progress at this moment:

```
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "-u") == 0 && *argv[2] == '0' && strcmp(argv[3], "-t") == 0) {
  unsigned int sections = atoi(argv[4]);
  unsigned int histogram[sections] = {};
  unsigned int k = 0;
  float limits[sections];
  float value = (float)255/sections;

  if (sections > 0) {
    cout << "The number of sections " << sections << "\n";
    cout << "Each section is " << value << "\n";

    cout << "The array of limits is : " << "\n";  
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sections; ++i) {
        limits[i] = value*i;
        cout << limits[i] << " ";
    }

       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            if (matrizGrey[i][j] >= 0 && matrizGrey[i][j] < limits[1] ) {
                histogram[0] = histogram[0]+1;
            }
            else if (matrizGrey[i][j] >= limits[1] && matrizGrey[i][j] < limites[2] ) {
                histogram[1] = histogram[1]+1;
            }
            else if (matrizGrey[i][j] >= limits[2] && matrizGrey[i][j] < limites[3] ) {
                histogram[2] = histogram[2]+1;
            }

        }
       }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The final result will be : " << "\n";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sections; ++i) {
        //histogram[i] = 0;
        cout << histogram[i] << " ";
    }
```

For example, with this "image": matrizGrey[0][0] = 100, matrizGrey[0][1] = 200, matrizGrey[1][0] = 125, matrizGrey[1][1] = 0, matrizGrey[2][0] = 255,
matrizGrey[2][1] = 7,

If I introduce a section number of 2 (which mean that my range will be [0, 127], [128, 255]) the result needs to be "4 2".
This is a little example, but I need to do this for a random number of sections and for a random number of pixels too.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I do it recursive?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you'd implement a histogram function recursively. IIRC it works fine with a loop.

Comment: @Borgleader because I need to implement it for an undetermined number of sections.

Comment: @giorgioW Recursion always can be replaced with a simple loop and a `std::stack`.

Comment: @Borgleader I don't understand so much your answer, sorry :(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what I need to have is for each matrizGrey[i][j] element, in which range of the histogram will be. The problem is that the range is based of the parameter that the user introduces. So, I could't find any way to code it.

Comment: Your `if-else-if-else-if` in the middle needs to be a **loop** over the number of sections and you will break out after you have found the correct section and incremented the histogram. Also, make a variable called `px=matrizGrey[i][j]` so you don't keep typing it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {for (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
    px = matrizGrey[i][j];
         while (k < sections) {
     if (px > limits[k] && px <= limits[k+1] ) {
          histogram[k] = histogram[k]+1;
     }
     else {
     k++;
     } 
    }
            }
          }

Comment: @MarkSetchell Something like this? (Sorry, I don't know how to write the proper code format in the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a better aproximation to the solution, but I still have problems, because if the number of sections is big, it doesn't show all the elements.

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-u") == 0 && *argv[2] == '0' && strcmp(argv[3], "-t") == 0) {
  unsigned int sections = atoi(argv[4]);
  unsigned int histogram[sections] = {};
  unsigned int k = 0;
  float limits[sections];
  float value = (float)255/sections;

  if (sections > 0) {
    cout << "The number of sections " << sections << "\n";
    cout << "Each section is " << value << "\n";

    cout << "The array of limits is : " << "\n";   
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sections; ++i) {
        limits[i] = value*i;
        cout << limits[i] << " ";
    }

      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            px = matrizGrey[i][j];
            k = 0;
            while (k < sections) {
                if (px > limits[k] && px <= limits[k+1] ) {
                histogram[k]++;
                break;
                }
                else {
                k++;
                }   
            }
        }
      } 

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The final result will be: " << "\n";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sections; ++i) {
        //histogram[i] = 0;
        cout << histogram[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
  }
```

Comment: Reset k=0 before loop.

Comment: `break` out of innermost loop after incrementing histogram. Increment histogram with `histogram[k]++`.